# Respond to Headphone events when using MediaPlayer

Tags: android, media-player, headphones

I'm using the built in MediaPlayer class in Android 2.1 to play audio & video files. However when I plug my headphones in and press the play pause button on them it fires up the built in music player which then plays as well as my app.

Is there a way to either register as being the app that wants those events so that people can control the playback of my app with their headphone controls? Alternatively is there some other way to get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should hook into the ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON intent: [Documentation.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON)

Comment: bingo, thanks. This post helped a lot for future peeps looking: http://android.amberfog.com/?p=415